# Calling method from header not working? [C]

Tags: c

So I'm calling a simple method from a header file to the main C file and it's not working. Any clue?

`Main`

```
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 5;
    int numArray[2] = {a, b};
    displayNumbers(numArray, 2);
    doubleIt(a);
    doubleIt(b);
    displayNumbers(numArray, 2);
    return(0);
}
```

`Header`

```
int doubleIt(int x) {
    return 2 * x;
}

void displayNumbers(int x[], int numSize) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numSize - 1; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", x[i]));
    printf("%d", x[numSize - 1]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

The doubleIt method doesn't work.

Comment: and "doesn't work" means...?

Comment: Here is my output with the code above:
`2, 5`
`2, 5`

It should be this:
`2, 5`
`4, 10`

Comment: How can you tell it doesn't work?

Comment: Double it *returns* a modified value, and since you don't capture that value returned, there is no change in `a` or `b`.

Comment: you have to catch the return value: a = doubleIt(a);

Comment: Oh. I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question properly, you want to double the array and print the values, in your case if `a = 2` and `b = 5` then you want to double to `a = 4` and `b = 10`.
Modify these lines in your code as follows;

```
numArray[0] = doubleIt(a);
numArray[1] = doubleIt(b);
```

Hope this helps.